# Xampp 7.3.3 fresh install of WordPress 404 pages unless permalink is set to plain

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, xampp

I have been running xampp 7.3.3 for quite a while but i have recently installed 2 fresh installs of wordpress and if the permalinks are set to anything other than plain the pages are showing 404.

i have turned off all plugins and changed themes but the issue still happens

The home page will work ok
I have tried resaving permalinks
I have checked the Apache modules

Has anyone had this issue?

I am going to install a new version of xampp to see if it still happens.
edit: I have donea new install of the latest xampp and the same thing happens

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned that you checked the Apache modules but can you check this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265305/http-404-with-post-name-permalink) maybe you overlooked one of them?
Also do you have any Virtual hosts? I once had a similar issue with them.

Comment: thanks, I have gone through and it seems to be ok. I also uploaded it to a remote server there is the same issue (so being in another environment didn't make a difference).  I also created a new site on my remote test server and duplicated it down to my local xampp and as th custom links were already set up adding pages with the custom permalink set is working fine